# Adding a matplotlib patch to inline axis twice in an iPython notebook causes offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a matplotlib `patch` that I want to add to two different `axis` objects. Calling `ax1.add_patch(my_patch)` the first time leads to the correct result, but when I call `ax2.add_patch(my_patch)`, the patch is offset horizontally. Calling `add_patch` again after that does not change the offset.

This only seems to happen when using `%matplotlib inline`. Generating the figures in separate windows does not lead to the offset.

Is there anything I can do to avoid the offset when using `%matplotlib inline`?

Minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

grid = np.ones([10,10])
circle = Circle((5,5), 2)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.imshow(grid, interpolation='None')
ax1.add_patch(circle)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.imshow(grid, interpolation='None')
ax2.add_patch(circle)
```

[image]

Comment: That does look like a bug, Happens for me too. Workaround, generate the circle again before doing the second plot.

Comment: @user1901493: Thanks for the confirmation. I [opened an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8507).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because adding the same `patch` (or, more generally, the same `Artist`) to more than one `Axes` [is not supported](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3776#issuecomment-62320620): the `Artist` can only hold the necessary transform for use in one `Axes`.

Future versions of matplotlib will [raise an exception](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3835) when the user tries to add an `Artist` that is already associated with an `Axes` object to another `Axes` object.